# Can't eject Windows 7 install disk to get drivers from Snow Leopard Install Disk

Tags: windows, bootcamp, install

Alright.  I'm angry at this.

I'm on a 2008 Macbook Pro, running snow leopard trying to install windows 7.

During the "find drivers" phase still in mac, it can't.
So according to apple I'm supposed to continue on anyways and use my snow leopard install disk to install the drivers.  But once I am installing windows 7, there is no way to eject disks because I don't have drivers installed yet.

How am I supposed to get around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, these answers don't apply. The problem is that the windows install disc won't eject but you can't get windows up and running until the drivers are installed from the mac OS disc. But in order to get to the point where you need to install the drivers, you need to use the windows disc.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the machine off.  Turn it on again, and hold down the trackpad button. The disc should eject.

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh1750.html

> Restart and hold down the mouse or trackpad button until the disc ejects.

(The other suggestions don't apply; you're not in MacOSX yet, you don't have an eject hole, and you have an Intel machine so the firmware thing won't work.)

The other Apple support page is here:-

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2801?viewlocale=en_UShttp://support.apple.com/kb/HT2801?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to eject the CD in Windows:

1. Click the Start menu & choose Computer
2. Bring up the context menu for the CD by either right-clicking it or selecting (but not opening it) it then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
3. There should be an option to eject the CD in the context menu

You could try downloading and installing the [Boot Camp Update 3.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1443) while booted in Windows. This update should install the Boot Camp drivers even if no previous version of the drivers have been installed yet.

If those don't work, you can hold the mouse button down after turning on the Mac, or you can startup in OS X to eject the CD, then reboot into Windows. Hold <kbd>Option</kbd> down at startup to choose whether to boot OS X or Windows.